# Need htaccess rewrite rule using wp slug

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Need heaccess rule for following condition

**SITEURL/slug** to **SITEURL/cache/slug.html**

ie

http://192.168.1.52/development/icache/hello-world/

to

http://192.168.1.52/development/icache/cache/hello-world.html

Comment: cache is your category? or it will be same for all URLS? I think you can do something in WP's permalinks settings to have similar structure i.e. in custom settings have " /cache/%postname%.html " in dasboard here: /wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Comment: No its my cache folder, This is for my new plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /development/icache/
RewriteRule ^hello-wo/$ /development/icache/cache/checkout.html? [L]
```